# What decides ductility of a substance- youngs modulus or the plastic limit of the substance?

Tags: elasticity, matter

Given two materials A and B such that a has higher young modulus as well as plastic 
limit than B , which of the two is more ductile?

Comment: Related: [Is Young's modulus a measure of stiffness or elasticity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/522296/238167)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Materials which can undergo plastic deformation without undergoing failure are called ductile. Youngs modulus determines the elasticity of the material and the yield point is the stress at which the material undergoes considerable deformation (usually 0.2%). These factors have nothing to do with ductility.

Comment: Poissons ratio is generally valid only in the elastic regime. Ductility is plastic deformation.

Comment: I know that. This is an observation made. Brittle materials have a low poisson's ratio and undergo failure easily without considerable deformation

Comment: And rubber undergoes lots of elastic deformation and isnt necessarily plastic...

Comment: I was answeing in the context. Youngs modulus or yield point dont have any effect on ductility.

Comment: That is correct, so why bring in another parameter that also does not apply?

Comment: Ok i will my answer to avoid any confusions.

Comment: Steel yield is usually defined as 0.2 % strain. Sometime as 0.5% extension ( under load) which is about the same except for high strength steels.  And, as noted, it has nothing to do with ductility.

Comment: Should i conclude that the rupture point is the only thing that i should bother about when considering about ductility?

Answer (score 1):

I'll list some of the factors here.

Ductility has to do with the nondirectionality of the interatomic bonds in the material. If those bonds have preferred directions and bond angles, then adjacent atoms cannot slip and slide past one another easily, which is key to furnishing ductility. This means that in an ideally ductile material, the nature of the bonds between its atoms must be maximally metallic in nature and exhibit no covalency.

Ductility is limited by the exhaustion of dislocation mobility mechanisms; if we try to further deform the material beyond that point the material begins to develop microcracks which then lead to failure. The most common causes of dislocation exhaustion are 1) pinning of dislocations at point defects in the crystalline structure of the material and 2) pileup of dislocations at grain boundaries.

Ductility can then be enhanced by increasing the purity of the material so as to eliminate the presence of foreign atoms as substitutions or interstitials within the crystal lattice, by furnishing a mechanism of dislocation climb that is active at the service temperature of the material so as to unlock the dislocations from point defects, and by allowing dislocation travel across grain boundaries.

These microstructural effects are very important but unfortunately difficult to deliberately design into a metallic alloy. The reason for the outstanding ductility of, for example, pure silver and gold is that their bonding is entirely metallic and dislocations in them can move across grain boundaries.